# Analytic spread of localization of an ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, localization

Let $J$ be an ideal in a Noetherian local ring $(R,m)$.  It is well known that for any prime ideal $p\in Spec(R)$, $l(J_p)\leq l(J)$, where $l(J)$ is the analytic spread of $J$.

**Q) Are there examples of ideals $J$ such that $l(J_p)\leq l(J)-1$ for all $p\supset J$ such that $ht p=ht J+1$ and $J^n\neq J^{(n)}$ for some $n$ (where $J^{(n)}$ is the nth symbolic power)?**

Comment: For $p=m$, clearly $l(J_p)=l(J)$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: I believe if $R$ is a regular local ring of dimension 3 and $P$ is any prime ideal of height 2 which is not a complete intersection, then $l(P)=3, l(P_P)=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(R, \mathfrak{m}): = \mathbb{C}[[x,y,z]]$ a formal power series. Let $J = (x^2, xy, xz) = \mathfrak{m}(x)$. We can check that $\ell(J) = 3$, $J^{(n)} = (x^n)$. This ideal satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case the ideal J is integrally closed. Is it always true  that ideals which satisfies these conditions (other than equimultiple ideals) are always integrally closed?

Comment: In the construction $J$, we replace $\mathfrak{m}$ by any $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal. Now we choose a non-integrally closed ideal (for example $(x^2, y^2, z^2)$) we have a non-integrally closed ideal that satisfies the requirements.